# facebook chat using asmack, user presence change delay

Tags: android, facebook, xmpp, smack

I am creating a facebook chat client using asmack library. Creating a connection, retrieval of contacts, establishing a chat, everything goes fine. However, when a user goes offline, it takes a while (about a minute or so) before my

> presenceChanged

method in the RosterListener is executed. When a user goes online, presenceChanged method is executed almost immediately. Code I am using is just a simple RosterListener:

> roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
>    // Ignored events
>    public void entriesAdded(Collection addresses) {}
>    public void entriesDeleted(Collection addresses) {}
>    public void entriesUpdated(Collection addresses) {}
>    public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
>       //do something to add/remove contact from list
>    }
>   });

Is this something Facebook related? Or Smack related? Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using asmack in android using my own openfire server and the presence works fine. I think its kinda facebook related because even on facebook website sometime it happens that you see a person online and start a chat, it eventually changes the status to offline.
Try removing or adding a friend to see if you roster works, show a log in the method enteries updated. if the entries are instantly updated than it means that this is a facebook related issue.

Comment: thanx, I will check the thing with adding/removing contacts.